# How to access a component property inside ng-template inside another component?

Tags: angular, angular-template

I'd like to know how to access a component property when the component is inside an `ng-template` and is also inside a component content. Like this:

```
<app-foo [num]="comp.num">
  <ng-template>
    <!-- Doesn't work -->
    <app-one ref-comp></app-one>
  </ng-template>

<!-- Works -->
  <app-one ref-comp></app-one>
</app-foo>
```

I've created a minimal stackblitz here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-yxeknr?file=src/app/app.component.html

My requirements is that `app-one` will stay inside `ng-template` and that the `ng-template` will be inside `app-foo`

I also don't want to use `ViewChild` to get `app-one` as I may have mutliple app-num components (app-one, app-two,..).

Comment: I can't see where you try accessing the component property

Comment: in `comp.num` in the first line of code snippet

Comment: `@Raz` so basically your question is how to pass ng-template to child component?

Comment: how passing ng-template to child component will help me get a property of the nested child component that inside the ng-template?

Comment: I see your problem

Answer (score 0):

`ng-template` is never directly rendered in the DOM, angular even replaces it with a comment (see https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#the-ng-template)

Therefor you can not reference it components in it unless it they are really rendered.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I know it never renders in the DOM, I'm looking for more thorough-full explanation here please